# Slovakia Sitecore User Group goes virtual on 16th June 2020

Tags: discussion, status-completed, community-event

Date/Time(CEST): June 16, 2020, 5:00 p.m.

Date/Time(UTC): June 16, 2020, 3:00 p.m.

Location: Microsoft Teams

RSVP and details: https://www.eventbrite.com/e/slovakia-sug-meetup-2-tickets-108067189874?aff=sse

Twitter: @chorpo

[image]